# Grocery crud set_relation

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

```
$crud->set_relation('seo_url', 'db_projects','seo');
```

On **insert/update** crud add **id** (primary key ) from db_projects to **seo_url** field. How can I add **seo** from db_projects not **id** (primary key) to seo_url field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this situation I think the only solution is to actually create a custom dropdown list with [field_type](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/field_type#dropdown-field) method. So in your case you will have:

```
$seo_results = array();
foreach ($this->db->get('db_projects')->result() as $row) {
    $seo_results[$row->seo] = $row->seo;
} 
$crud->field_type('seo_url', 'dropdown', $seo_results);
```